Can Stim tell what to measure to get a certain stabilizer group?
In Stim, given a stabilizer group $S_1$, is there a way to find a set of measurement that we should perform to move to another stabilizer group $S_2$? For example, suppose we have a 5-qubit code state, and we want to know what to measure to move to Steane code state. Can we know what to measure using Stim?

There's no method like this in Stim. It's a bit too wide in terms of strategies for it to be a good method (e.g. by decode/encode? by lattice surgery? by temporary concatenation with a third code?).
If you come up with such a strategy, and turn it into a circuit, that's where stim comes in for sampling/analyzing it.
